# Use variable to sort MySQL table

Tags: mysql, variables

I want to use the `name` variable to sort my SQL table.

```
if (isset($_POST['name']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}
```

I've printed the variable and it is `modelName`. Now I want to sort the table with the field `modelName`.

If I use this code, it doesn't work:

```
$statement = $pdo->query('SELECT `ID`, `modelName`, `datecreated` FROM `modeldb` ORDER BY "' . $name . '"');
```

But if I use this code, it works:

```
$statement = $pdo->query('SELECT `ID`, `modelName`, `datecreated` FROM `modeldb` ORDER BY modelName');
```

Am I using the variable wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to programming,

you should echo your SQL query like below to evaluate what kind of query your input generates.

`echo 'SELECT ID, modelName, datecreated FROM modeldb ORDER BY "' . $name . '"'`

you will find that the `"` are not required at all.

one rule of programming is that never trust the user input. here you are injecting the data which you received from `$_POST`
so you should validate your input like

```
$sortableColumns = ['id','modelname','datecreated']
if(in_array(strtolower($name),$sortableColumns)){
  $statement = $pdo->query('SELECT ID, modelName, datecreated FROM modeldb ORDER BY ' . $name )
}else{
  $statement = $pdo->query('SELECT ID, modelName, datecreated FROM modeldb ORDER BY id');
}
```

Let me know any other guide you want.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot.<br/> but i still did not realy understand the different ways of putting a variable inside a string in php:                                `echo '<div class="dbview" onclick="startViewer(' . $dModel['ID'] . ')"><b>' . $dModel['modelName'] . '</b><br/><br/>' . $dModel['datecreated'] . '</div>';`               here the string exits at  ...startViewer('   - i don't know how to do that diferently...

Comment: @user61765 it's better to write php in between HTML, eg. `<div class="dbview" onclick="startViewer('<?php echo $dModel['ID'] ?> ')"><b><?php echo  $dModel['modelName'] ?></b><br/><br/><?php echo $dModel['datecreated'] ?></div>`